# Python crashes when I try to import GDAL after re-installing it

Tags: python, gdal

A while back I went through the installation process for GDAL by installing the core components and then the Python/GDAL bindings.  Everything was fine when I would type in `from osgeo import gdal`.  However, I had to uninstall and reinstall everything due to a problem I was having.  Now when I type in `from osgeo import gdal`, Python crashes and I get the message that it has stopped working.  When I click on "Close the Program" Python restarts.

I've looked to see if there was anything left over from the previous install, but couldn't find anything.

Any ideas on something I could try?

Comment: What version of GDAL and where did you get the installer for it?

Comment: I used the instructions here . . . https://pythongisandstuff.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/installing-gdal-and-ogr-for-python-on-windows/

I downloaded the following files:
gdal-111-1800-x64-core.msi
GDAL-1.11.1.win-amd64-py2.7.msi


Then I followed the above instructions.

Comment: I downloaded those files from this web page . .     http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1800-x64-gdal-1-11-mapserver-6-4.zip